# Is 'University doctorate' a correct way to describe someone who has done a PhD. at a particular university?

Tags: expressions

The term 'University graduate'(For e.g. Stanford graduate) is ambiguous in the sense that it does not indicate if the concerned individual has an undergraduate, post-graduate or a PhD. degree from the university.

So, I wanted to know whether the above ambiguity can be eliminated by describing the individual as University undergraduate, University graduate and University doctorate to indicate completion of undergraduate, graduate and doctorate degrees at the university.

For e.g:

If A has done a PhD. from Stanford University, Can we call A as a Stanford doctorate?

Comment: A is a doctor, not a doctorate. A doctor has a doctorate, and you can say it's a Stanford doctorate.

Comment: For instance, The phrase -  'Jon, a Stanford doctor', has a connotation of a medical doctor than someone having done PhD. from Stanford.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard people described as "a PhD", particularly in an American context.

For example: "She's a Stanford PhD", or "I'm a PhD".

A few usages found with Google:

https://irevolutions.org/2011/10/05/its-official-im-a-phd/

[https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimaphd/]

Comment: yes, this is a good suggestion. But I am also interested in understanding if there is any semantic/syntactic impropriety in using 'A is a University doctorate' to refer to a someone who has done a PhD from the university.

Comment: 'A is a University doctorate' seems strange to me.  Maybe better: 'A holds a University doctorate' or 'A has been awarded a University doctorate'.  I agree that "doctorate" is the degree, not the person; so we should not say that a person is a doctorate.

Comment: The doctorate is the degree; the doctor is the person who receives the degree. All doctorates are equivalent, so _`University` PhD_  isn't used. If you do use it, you are implying pragmatically that a PhD from `University` is either much better or much inferior to the norm. So be careful you understand the context.

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to know whether the above ambiguity can be eliminated by
>   describing the individual as University undergraduate, University
>   graduate and University doctorate to indicate completion of
>   undergraduate, graduate and doctorate degrees at the university.

No.  You can't do this.  First of all, "undergraduate" means someone who hasn't yet obtained their Bachelor's degree.  So it would be quite wrong to use the word "undergraduate" to indicate completion of their degree.

Actually, the OED defines "bachelor" as meaning someone who has obtained their Bachelor's degree but not their Master's.  ("One who has taken the first or lowest degree at a university, who is not yet a master of the Arts" - OED.)  However, you can't in practice go around calling such people "bachelors".  It's too ambiguous, because the word "bachelor" has other meanings, and you won't be widely understood.  Nor (even disregarding the polysemy) would "Stanford bachelor" necessarily mean someone who had obtained their degree from Stanford.  It could equally mean someone who's obtained a degree (possibly from elsewhere) and who now lives in Stanford or studies at Stanford.

Nor can you use the word "graduate" to mean that the person has completed a postgraduate degree.  A university graduate is someone who has completed any university degree.  It doesn't need to be a postgraduate degree.  Someone with a Bachelor's degree is a graduate; so is someone with a Master's; and so is someone with a doctorate.